# Need replacement cones for Shimano front hub

Tags: hub

I am rebuilding a Shimano HB-M475 front hub, but having trouble finding the replacement cones. This one has the M9 axle, but all of the replacement cones I have found are for a M10 axles. I need to know where I can find these cones for a 9 mm axle.

Comment: I bought some new cones for my Shimano hub from [this vendor](http://myworld.ebay.ca/dragon_spinz?ssPageName=ADME:L:OU:US:1181) back in July.  Dunno if they have yours.  Also purchased an entire new hub from [this vendor](https://www.huskybicycles.com/).  Eventually replaced the entire wheel (through Peter White), though, since the original hub was apparently bent and it was cheaper to buy a new wheel than to rebuild.

Comment: I am also rebuilding a Shimano HB-M475 front hub with 9 mm axle. I only find front M10 replacement cones. Where did you end up buying your cones for your Shimano 9 mm axle?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this Shimano TechDoc](http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/EV/bikecomponents/HB/EV-HB-M475-2197B_v1_m56577569830647979.pdf), the axle of HB-M475 (Front hub, 100mm OLD, 6-bolt disc mount) is M10.

If you find a different model number marked on the hub, [Shimano techdocs are listed here](http://techdocs.shimano.com/techdocs/index.jsp).